# Run time error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I get the following error message in vb.net when I try to run the program

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Error   1   Unable to copy file "C:\Users\Mr. M Yoosuf Hassan\Desktop\CD\Software (full version)\Airline Reservation System - Copy\Airline Reservation System\Airline2.mdb" to "bin\Debug\Airline2.mdb". Could not find file 'C:\Users\Mr. M Yoosuf Hassan\Desktop\CD\Software (full version)\Airline Reservation System - Copy\Airline Reservation System\Airline2.mdb'.   Airline Reservation System

Comment: It can't find the file.  I don't know where it is either, can't look over your shoulder.  Where is it?

Comment: no bt d fact iz d file iz saved in the bin debug folder it is already there

Comment: can you be more specific on what are you doing exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to understand if you wrote proper words rather than text abbreviations...

It sounds in your comment like you're saying that the file is in the bin\debug folder already, but the error message above says that you're unable to copy it TO the bin\debug folder, so is it possible that you've put the parameters to the copy function the wrong way around?